# Error 1242(21000) after creating following trigger and performing delete operation

Tags: database-design, mysql-5.7, dbms

I want to create a trigger which copies the record from **maintable** to **undostack** before deleting it in **maintable** and undostack table acts a stack of 5 records space and this trigger performs a push operation.

This is my trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER undo_op
BEFORE DELETE ON maintable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
```

When undostack is not full

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u)<5 THEN
INSERT INTO undostack VALUES(((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM undostack)+1),
(SELECT id FROM maintable WHERE id=OLD.id),
(SELECT descp FROM maintable WHERE descp=OLD.descp),
(SELECT cat FROM maintable WHERE cat=OLD.cat),
(SELECT dat FROM maintable WHERE dat=OLD.dat),
(SELECT amt FROM maintable WHERE amt=OLD.amt));
```

When undostack is full and has to delete the oldest record entered by updating. here undo_no acts as pointer.

```
ELSE
```

1<-2

```
UPDATE undostack SET
id=(SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=2),
descp=(SELECT descp FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=2),
cat=(SELECT cat FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=2),
dat=(SELECT dat FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=2),
amt=(SELECT amt FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=2)
WHERE undo_no=1;
```

2<-3

```
UPDATE undostack SET
id=(SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=3),
descp=(SELECT descp FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=3),
cat=(SELECT cat FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=3),
dat=(SELECT dat FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=3),
amt=(SELECT amt FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=3)
WHERE undo_no=2;
```

3<-4

```
UPDATE undostack SET
id=(SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=4),
descp=(SELECT descp FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=4),
cat=(SELECT cat FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=4),
dat=(SELECT dat FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=4),
amt=(SELECT amt FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=4)
WHERE undo_no=3;
```

4<-5

```
UPDATE undostack SET
id=(SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=5),
descp=(SELECT descp FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=5),
cat=(SELECT cat FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=5),
dat=(SELECT dat FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=5),
amt=(SELECT amt FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack)u WHERE undo_no=5)
WHERE undo_no=4;
```

5<-update with the values which are to be deleted from maintable

```
UPDATE undostack SET
id=(SELECT id FROM maintable WHERE id=OLD.id),
descp=(SELECT descp FROM maintable WHERE descp=OLD.descp),
cat=(SELECT id FROM maintable WHERE cat=OLD.cat),
dat=(SELECT id FROM maintable WHERE dat=OLD.dat),
amt=(SELECT amt FROM maintable WHERE amt=OLD.amt)
WHERE undo_no=5;
END IF;
END
```

The trigger has no errors
but when I execute

```
DELETE FROM maintable WHERE id=10;
```

There is following error

ERROR 1242 (21000):Subquery returns more than 1 row

Please help me with this error

I'm using MySQL 5.7.3

Comment: This code as nothing to do with Microsoft SQL server. Please remove the tag.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this, is(for example undo_no 1)

```
UPDATE undostack SET
id=(SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack) u WHERE undo_no=2),
descp=(SELECT descp FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack) u WHERE undo_no=2),
cat=(SELECT cat FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack) u WHERE undo_no=2),
dat=(SELECT dat FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack) u WHERE undo_no=2),
amt=(SELECT amt FROM (SELECT * FROM undostack) u WHERE undo_no=2)
WHERE undo_no=1;
```

By using `(SELECT * FROM undostack) u` Mysql generates a table which it uses to select your data.

usully i would say make this better in your pplication code, but five rows is very samll

Comment: I have replaced the code, but now when I perform a delete operation there is a ERROR(1242): Subquer returns more than 1 row

Comment: you have to test your aproach first when you try to uodate you write SET a= b b can only be **one** value. as your message suggest, some seletcs return `more than one` value, now you have to select  which one you need